# (Sails V1 + MongoDB) how to Create Dynamic collection/table in MongoDB using SailsJS?

Tags: sails.js, sails-mongo

i want to create Dynamic collection/table in mongoDB using SailsJS.

## Example

1- New User Registration.

2- On Registration Success, User's Unique (userID + table) table Create in MongoDB.

3- How can we access this table (UserID + table) from SailsJS.

Please help,
Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by Dynamic table? Do you need to implement a user registration functionality ?

Comment: no it was just an example to explain.

Comment: I guess there are workarounds for that . I think this may help you  - https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1160

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-inverse-model

```
var sim = require('sails-inverse-model');

var folder_controllers = "/your/project/sails/api/"; //if folder_models == "" then: no generate controllers
var folder_models = "/your/project/sails/api/"; //if folder_models == "" then: no generate models
var folder_views = "/your/project/sails/"; //if folder_models == "" then: no generate views

//                host       port         database           views         models          controllers
sim.generatemg('localhost', 27017, 'my_name_collection', folder_views, folder_models, folder_controllers);
```